# How to prevent caching of static files in embedded Jetty instance?

Tags: caching, jetty, embedded-jetty

I want to prevent my CSSs from being cached on the browser side. How can I do it in embedded Jetty instance?

If I were using xml configuration file, I would add lines like:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>cacheControl</param-name>
  <param-value>max-age=0,public</param-value>
</init-param>
```

How I can turn that into the code?

Right now I start Jetty this way:

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();

Server server = new Server();
SocketConnector connector = new SocketConnector();
// Set some timeout options to make debugging easier.
// 1 hour
connector.setMaxIdleTime( 1000 * 60 * 60 );
connector.setSoLingerTime( -1 );
connector.setPort( 8081 );
server.setConnectors( new Connector[] { connector } );

WebAppContext bb = new WebAppContext();
bb.setServer( server );
bb.setContextPath( "/" );
bb.setWar( "src/webapp" );

server.addHandler( bb );
```

I think I should search setControlCache somewhere in the WebAppContext area of responsibility.

Any advices on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally use a ServletHolder, like this:

```
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(MyServlet.class);
servletHolder.setInitParameter("cacheControl","max-age=0,public"); 
context.addServlet(servletHolder, "myservletpath");
```

While this does not *exactly* match your code you should be able to figure it out from there ?

Answer (score 2):

Duh, how to do just the opposite [How to configure cache for static resources in web.xml for Jetty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906745/how-to-configure-cache-for-static-resources-in-web-xml-for-jetty)?

Answer (score 1):

And here's just a working code with no need to figure out, guess and try. It's provided with respect to code in question and jetty 6. For jetty 7 and higher need to change Context to ServletContextHandler.

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();

Server server = new Server();
SocketConnector connector = new SocketConnector();
// Set some timeout options to make debugging easier.
// 1 hour
connector.setMaxIdleTime( 1000 * 60 * 60 );
connector.setSoLingerTime( -1 );
connector.setPort( 8081 );
server.setConnectors( new Connector[] { connector } );

//--- The difference with code in question starts here

DefaultServlet defaultServlet = new DefaultServlet();
ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(defaultServlet);
holder.setInitParameter("useFileMappedBuffer", "false");
holder.setInitParameter("cacheControl", "max-age=0, public");

Context bb = new Context();
bb.setResourceBase("src/webapp");
bb.addServlet(holder, "/");

//--- Done. Caching is off!

server.addHandler( bb );
// Run server as usual with server.run();
```

My sample also sets useFileMappedBuffer to false which is needed for not blocking files on a disk if you are developing on Windows by any reason.

Answer (score 0):

I use resourceHandler for static contents.
Here's a code working fine on Jetty 9.

```
    ResourceHandler rh = new ResourceHandler();
    rh.setResourceBase([your_resource_base_dir]);
    rh.setCacheControl("no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate");
```