# How to configure cache for static resources in web.xml for Jetty?

Tags: configuration, caching, jetty, embedded-jetty, cache-control

I was reading this:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/LastModifiedCacheControl

It says

> The Jetty default servlet allows the cache control header to
>   be set for static content by using the cacheControl init parameter
>   using:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>cacheControl</param-name>
    <param-value>max-age=3600,public</param-value>
</init-param>
```

However, I am not sure that I am using the default servlet. At least
such configuration is not in web.xml:

```xml
<web-app>
    <display-name>Wicket QuickStart</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>configuration</param-name>
        <param-value>development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>quickstart</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>wicket.quickstart.WicketApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>quickstart</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I would like to configure cache for static resources such as:

`/src/webapp/*`, i.e.: `/src/webapp/images, /src/webapp/css, /src/webapp/js`, etc.

What should I add into my `web.xml`?

Answer (score 9):

Need to add the following to your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cacheControl</param-name>
        <param-value>max-age=3600,public</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: With wicket the static resources are actually served with WicketServlet, so this does not help :(

Comment: Oh, I see.  I think within your Application.init() you need to set the following.

getResourceSettings().setDefaultCacheDuration(3600);

Comment: If you're not using Wicket, like me, but you are using Jetty 8 or later, change org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet to org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet