# GWT *nocache* and deploying app in Jetty 7

Tags: gwt, jetty, no-cache

In [this gwt web](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html) says to place a *.htaccess config file like this to avoid caching main javascript gwt application.

```
<Files *.nocache.*>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresDefault "now"
  Header merge Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
</Files>

<Files *.cache.*>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 year"
</Files>
```

Is there a way to do the same with Jetty ? (whithout needing to use httpd jetty module)

Answer (score 0):

This answer shows how to disable/enable caching for all files served with Jetty:

[How to prevent caching of static files in embedded Jetty instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/696777/270662)

I think to set up custom caching settings for individual files (e.g. *nocache*), one must use a filter and set the headers manually in the HttpResponseObject for files matching the request URI such as described here:

[Servlet filter for browser caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3374874/270662)